# Use spotify app in background with API

Tags: spotify, spotify-app

I have a spotify app that I am intereacting with using my website, doing things like adding to playlist and playing.
However I want this to happen in the background rather than popping up the app each time I add a track to a playlist.  Anyone know if there's a way to do this?

Comment: could you explain your app a little more?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no support for background Spotify Apps, so you need to keep your app opened to prevent it from being unloaded.

There is more information about this on the [Spotify Developer Guidelines](https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/apps/guidelines/developer/#loading-unloading).